# Python compare/replace keys in dic with values of another dic

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to compare/replace a value of a dictionary with a key of another dictionary  like so :

```
DicA = {'abc' : 1 , 'def' : 2 , 'ghi' : 3}

DicB = {3: 'klm' , 2 : 'nop' ,1 : 'qrs'}
```

Result should be:

```
DicC = {'abc' : 'qrs' , 'def' : 'nop' ,'ghi' : 'klm'}
```

So the Value "1" in `DicA` got replaced with "qrs" because they key in `DicB(1)` matched with the Value in `DicA(1)` so the result is -> abc : qrs.

1. How do I compare the  key with the value of another dictionary?(for loops)?
2. How do I replace it afterwards?
3. Is there a way to use the implemented map() function for this? E.g.

```
map(lambda dicA, dicB):
```

Comment: Note that a dictionary is normally called "dict" for short. "Dic" sounds like "dick", so you may want to avoid it.

Comment: Oh , your right...I'm sorry about that..

Comment: There is no value `"1"` in `DicA`, nor a key `"1"`. Keep in mind that `dict`s are not guaranteed to be ordered/sorted, so `"abc"` is not even the "first" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a dictionary comprehension:

```
dicA= {'abc': 1, 'def': 2, 'ghi': 3}
dicB= {3: 'klm', 2: 'nop', 1: 'qrs'}

dicC = {key: dicB[val] for key, val in dicA.items()}
```

However, this will fail if `dicB` does not have a key for one of the items in `dicA`.  You can get around this by using the `get` dictionary method which accepts a default value, as pointed out by MCBama.

```
dicA = {'abc': 1, 'def': 2, 'ghi': 3}
dicB = {2: 'nop', 1: 'qrs'}

dicC = {key: dicB.get(val,"") for key, val in dicA.items()}
# {'abc': 'qrs', 'def': 'nop', 'ghi': ''}
```

Comment: Instead of `defaultdict` you can also just do a `get` on it. Ex: `dicC = {key: dicB.get(val,"") for key, val in dicA.items()}`

Comment: This helped me alot! Thank you very much. However i would've never get the idea to do it that way. I always tried it with for loops and never got to the correct outcome. Guess i still have to learn a ton.

Comment: @MCBama That's a much better implementation!

Comment: Is there any way to implement map though? My friend said he did it easily with map so i*m trying it out , but i cant get anything to work..